# Android - Creating MenuItem with Icon not working

Tags: android

I am trying to add a menu item at runtime, with an Icon, but the Icon is not visible.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    createMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

private void createMenu(Menu menu) {
    // menu.clear();
    MenuItem miRateThisApp = menu.add(0, 0, 0,
            Constants.RATE_THIS_APP_STRING).setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    miRateThisApp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

            AppStoreUtil.goToMarket(getApplicationContext(),
                    Constants.PACKAGE_NAME);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The text shows up, click listener is working, but the icon is not visible. I have tried the same thing in the XML variant as well but same results.

XML Menu code which I tried earlier:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/lines"
    android:icon="@drawable/lines"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Lines"
    app:showAsAction="always">

</item>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `showAsAction`?

Comment: Yes, I did that when I was trying with the XML. Updated with question with this detail.

Comment: Is the icon a fixed size .png resource, or is it one of the other types of drawable such as a shape drawable which needs it's size defined?

Comment: It is a normal .png image